# Binary search on strings instead of numbers

Tags: c++, binary-search

I am reading up on binary search on an array of numbers and I believe I know how it works and how to implement it. Now I need to know how to do binary search on an array of strings ? I know binary search requires the array to be sorted already. suppose I have an array of strings already sorted how do I implement binary search on it ? I know if it was an array of numbers I would go to the middle index of the array and determin if the required search no is on the left or the right and do that recursively. How would i do that for strings?

Comment: It can be exactly the same.  C strings are just long numbers.

Comment: Do you mean that you have an array of strings? If so, it's the same thing. If you mean "search for a value within a string", unless you sort the characters in the string, you will more or less have to search through the string from start to end [There is a Boyer-Moore algorithm that is quite popular for LARGE string searches, but for small strings, it's typically no big deal to just search straight through]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the concept of "it is equal to" and "it is less than" are defined for the type you are working on, you can implement the algorithm. It does not matter if the values are numbers, letters, or custom objects. The following example demonstrates this concept:

```
template<typename Iterator>                                                                         
Iterator search(Iterator initial, Iterator final, const typename Iterator::value_type& value) {     

  if(value < *initial) {
    // bail out immediately    
     return final;
   }

  while(initial != final) {                                                                         
    auto mid = std::next(initial, std::distance(initial, final) / 2);                               
    if(*mid == value) {                                                                             
      return mid;                                                                                   
    } else if(*mid < value) {                                                                       
      initial = std::next(mid);                                                                     
    } else {                                                                                        
      final = std::prev(mid);                                                                       
    }                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                 
  return final;                                                                                     
}
```

As long as the operations `*mid == value` and `*mid < value` are defined, I can search in a container of any type (another requirement is that I must be able to randomly access my iterator).

This is by no means a full answer, and there are many more details involved, but hopefully you get the idea.

Full sample program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Iterator>
Iterator search(Iterator initial, Iterator final, const typename Iterator::value_type& value) {

  if(value < *initial) {
    // bail out immediately    
     return final;
   }

  while(initial != final) {
    auto mid = std::next(initial, std::distance(initial, final) / 2);
    if(*mid == value) {
      return mid;
    } else if(*mid < value) {
      initial = std::next(mid);
    } else {
      final = std::prev(mid);
    }
  }
  return final;
}


int main() {
  {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto it = search(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
    if(it == v.end()) {
      std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Found in position: " << std::distance(v.begin(), it)
                << " (value is : " << *it << ")" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  {
    std::vector<char> v {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    auto it = search(v.begin(), v.end(), 'd');
    if(it == v.end()) {
      std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Found in position: " << std::distance(v.begin(), it)
                << " (value is : " << *it << ")" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  {
    std::list<float> v {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it = search(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    if(it == v.end()) {
      std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Found in position: " << std::distance(v.begin(), it)
                << " (value is : " << *it << ")" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  {
    std::vector<char> v {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    auto it = search(v.begin(), v.end(), 'f');
    if(it == v.end()) {
      std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Found in position: " << std::distance(v.begin(), it)
                << " (value is : " << *it << ")" << std::endl;
    }
  }

}
```

Sample Run:

```
Found in position: 2 (value is : 3)
Found in position: 3 (value is : d)
Found in position: 1 (value is : 0)
Not Found!
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to assign a unique value to each letter (if you're doing English, that's easy; only 26 values), and compare the values of the first letter of each string. If the letters are the same, then you compare the second letter, and so on.

Comment: One could, say, use the ASCII code to do this, I presume? And then, if one follows that, use either `strcmp` or `std::string::operastor<` to actually do the comparison...

Comment: @MatsPetersson that does make sense. Thanks for clearing that up.At http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/ I could see that the string class does have relational operators. Could you kindly explain how they work.Preferably a new answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use array of `std::string`, it just the same since you have all compare operators.

so you just need to replace the type of the array and you can do the search as is for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same way. If you use `std::string`, it already has `operator==` and `operator <` which are all you need for binary search. If you just have character pointers, you can use `strcmp`, where a negative value is less than and 0 is equal.